# ASP.NET MVC connect to new database while app is running

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make an app which every user can install on his server and configure it after first launch. By configuring i mean add credentials to mysql, set site name, etc.

Is it possible to connect to database which isn't in code already? Can i use something like config file and connect to multiple different databases added from app admin panel?

That's all because user can have multiple databases and he need to manage them from application.

Comment: Are all the databases gonna have the same schema?

Comment: This might be of help to you: https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson02

Comment: I will prepare models for all possible databases.

Comment: You can create the required databases after or during the configuration process. We do it in SQL server by settings the initial catalog as master and execute create database, create table commands. If you are developing a web application that has many users all have their own database and configuration, consider searching and reading a bit about "developing multi-tenant web applications".